# HTMLKit Swift Parsing

Tags: html, css, swift

Parse between elements
eg

```
<span>7:33</span>AM          </dd>\n
<dt>Dinner</dt>\n          <dd id=\"Dinner\">\n            <span>12:23</span>PM          </dd>\n                                    <dt>Lunch</dt>\n          <dd id=\"Lunch\">\n            <span>2:43</span>PM          </dd>\n
```

how do I get "AM/PM" Values

```
    let test: [String] = document.querySelectorAll("span").compactMap({element in
        guard let span = document.querySelector("dt") else {
            return nil
        }
        
        return span.elementId
        
    })
```

this is just looping 7:33 nine time :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can solve this the same way you would do it on any other browser. The problem is not HTMLKit specific.

Since there is no way to select a HTML Text Node via CSS, you have to select its parent and then access the text via the `textContent` property or access the parent node's child nodes.

So here are some options to solve your problem, using HTMLKit as an example and the following sample DOM:

```swift
let html = """
<html>
<body>
<dl>
  <dt>Breakfast</dt>
  <dd id="Breakfast"><span>10:00</span>AM</dd>
  <dt>Dinner</dt>
  <dd id="Dinner"><span>12:23</span>PM</dd>
</dl>
</body>
</html>
"""

let doc = HTMLDocument(string: html)
let elements = doc.querySelectorAll("dd")
```

- Option 1: Select the `dd` elements and access the `textContent`

```swift
elements.forEach { ddElement in
  print(ddElement.textContent)
}

// Would produce:
// 10:00AM
// 12:23PM
```

- Option 2: Select the `dd` elements and iterate through their child nodes, while filtering out everything except for `HTMLText` nodes. Additionally you can provide your own custom filter:

```swift
elements.forEach { ddElement in
  let iter: HTMLNodeIterator = ddElement.nodeIterator(showOptions: [.text], filter: nil)
  iter.forEach { node  in
    let textNode = node as! HTMLText
    print(textNode.textContent)
  }
}

// Would produce:
// 10:00
// AM
// 12:23
// PM
```

- Option 3: Expanding on the previous option, you can provide a custom filter for the node iterator:

```swift
for dd in elements {
  let iter: HTMLNodeIterator = dd.nodeIterator(showOptions: [.text]) { node in
    if !node.textContent.contains("AM") && !node.textContent.contains("PM") {
        return .reject
    }
    return .accept
  }

  iter.forEach { node  in
    let textNode = node as! HTMLText
    print(textNode.textContent)
  }
}

// Would produce:
// AM
// PM
```

- Option 4: Wrap the `AM` and `PM` in their own `<span>` elements and access those, e.g. with `dd > span` selector:

```swift
doc.querySelectorAll("dd > span").forEach { elem in
   print(elem.textContent)
}

// Given the sample DOM would produce:
// 10:00
// 12:23

// if you wrap the am/pm in spans then you would also get those in the output
```

Your snippet produces: `["", ""]` with the sample DOM from above. Here is why:

```swift
let test: [String] = doc.querySelectorAll("span")
  .compactMap { element in  // element is a <span> HTMLElement

    // However the elements returned here are <dt> elements and not <span>
    guard let span = doc.querySelector("dt") else {
        return nil
    }
    // The <dt> elements in the DOM do not have IDs, hence an empty string is returned
    return span.elementId
  }
```

I hope this helps and clarifies some things.

Comment: Hi Iska, I am very appreciative of your answer and I'm sure many others will find this useful. I went with the option of 'Option 2'. Thank you for making the effort to provide an array of solutions. Thank you again. Saud